# How to dynamically always reference the next cell down in MIN function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I'm trying to create a dynamic `MIN` function in Excel that will always take a range is its argument, beginning with the next cell down. Here's a screenshot of what I *want* Excel to do from my spreadsheet:

[image: Excel_screenshot]

The problem is, when I hit `Enter`, Excel tells me that there's a problem with the formula.

Basically, I want to write a `MIN` function in cell C3 that looks at the range beneath, ending with cell C9, but that *always* start exactly 1 cell below (in this case, cell C4). This way, even if I want to insert a new row above the current Row 4, the `MIN` function will pick that up in its calculation as the first cell instead of shifting the range argument down to begin at C5.

I don't want to hard code cell C4 as the starting reference in the `MIN` function, but I can't figure out how to do it without getting an error in Excel. I've also tried using the `OFFSET` function in a similar way, but I get the same error. I just need to get the *next* cell's address but then use it within the `MIN` function.

Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

ADDRESS returns a string representation of a cell address. You need to convert that to a usable cell address with INDIRECT.

```
=min(indirect(address(row()+1, column())&":C9"))
'depending on what C9 is supposed to do maybe this,
=min(indirect(address(row()+1, column())):C9)
```

However, there seems to be better ways of accomplishing this.

```
=min(index(C:C, row()+1):C$9)
```